# Apostrophe numeric character reference not converted when displayed?

Tags: php, html, html-escape-characters

I'm pulling the following string out of a database `'86` and running it through an escape function for security reasons, since this is user-defined data:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

What I get back in return is `&#039;86`.

So `htmlspecialchars` is escaping the apostraphe and converting it to its [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) (as opposed to its [character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), I guess because there isn't one for the apostrophe).

The problem I have is that when the text is displayed on a browser, the browser isn't displaying it as `'` and instead just prints `&#039;86`. Viewing source for the page confirms it's sourced at `&#039;86` as well (so it's not double encoded). I tried several browsers.

The content-type header for from the server is properly set to `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Any ideas why it wouldn't be displayed properly?

Comment: Seems like a case of "demo or didn't happen". If the received content is actually being treated as HTML, HTML entities will be decoded when parsing the document.

Comment: Indeed, I was overlooking something which I discovered while preparing a demo :)

Answer (score 1):

Jumped the gun, looks like it was actually being output as `&amp;#039;86`. I was looking at the web inspector in Chrome and not actually viewing the page source. The web inspector was converting the `&amp;` to `&` leading to my confusion.